# Setting up DB on copied Rails App: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "settings" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My old computer failed me so I copied my rails app onto a new computer for development. I created the postgresql database and tried running rake db:migrate but get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "settings" does not exist LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"settings"'::regclass
                                          ^ :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"settings"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:822:in `async_exec' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:822:in `block in exec_no_cache' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:822:in `exec_no_cache' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:137:in `exec_query' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:976:in `column_definitions' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:187:in `columns' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:93:in `block in prepare_default_proc' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:44:in `yield' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:44:in `columns' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:214:in `columns' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:223:in `columns_hash' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:64:in `block in valid?' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:64:in `each' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:64:in `all?' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:64:in `valid?' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing' /Users/username/Documents/OLD MACBOOK FILES/username/Rails/chester/lib/etsy_api.rb:17:in `<module:EtsyAPI>' /Users/username/Documents/OLD MACBOOK FILES/username/Rails/chester/lib/etsy_api.rb:1:in `<top (required)>' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require' /Users/username/Documents/OLD MACBOOK FILES/username/Rails/chester/config/initializers/custom.rb:1:in `<top (required)>' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in `block in load_config_initializer' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:647:in `load_config_initializer' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!' /Users/username/Documents/OLD MACBOOK FILES/username/Rails/chester/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:379:in `block in run_tasks_blocks' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>' PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "settings" does not exist LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"settings"'::regclass
                                          ^ /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:822:in `async_exec' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:822:in `block in exec_no_cache' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:822:in `exec_no_cache' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:137:in `exec_query' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:976:in `column_definitions' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:187:in `columns' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:93:in `block in prepare_default_proc' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:44:in `yield' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:44:in `columns' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:214:in `columns' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:223:in `columns_hash' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:64:in `block in valid?' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:64:in `each' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:64:in `all?' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:64:in `valid?' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing' /Users/username/Documents/OLD MACBOOK FILES/username/Rails/chester/lib/etsy_api.rb:17:in `<module:EtsyAPI>' /Users/username/Documents/OLD MACBOOK FILES/username/Rails/chester/lib/etsy_api.rb:1:in `<top (required)>' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require' /Users/username/Documents/OLD MACBOOK FILES/username/Rails/chester/config/initializers/custom.rb:1:in `<top (required)>' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in `block in load_config_initializer' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:647:in `load_config_initializer' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!' /Users/username/Documents/OLD MACBOOK FILES/username/Rails/chester/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:379:in `block in run_tasks_blocks' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval' /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>' Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I also tried rake db:setup and other commands but got the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any initializers that try to access the database? Also, it would be better if you dumped the stack trace in as a code block rather than a block quote, much easier to read that way.

Comment: You are a genius -- it was related to the initializers! I commented out those lines and it is now working. Also thanks for the tip regarding code block vs block quote..am new to this. Will keep it in mind for future posts :)

Comment: I just walked through the stack trace to see if there was anything suspicious, initializers trying to access things is a common source of problems as they run while the app is starting up in order to run rake commands (such as `db:setup`). BTW, that SQL is what ActiveRecord uses to figure out table structure with PostgreSQL.